# logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 4, 1, 2) vs (None, 2))

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```html
def train(data,model=False):

    X= np.array([i[0] for i in data]).reshape(-1,len(data[0][0]),1)
    y=np.array([i[1] for i in data])

    if model==False:
        network = models.Sequential()

        network.add(layers.Dense(32,input_shape=[None, len(X[0]), 1], activation='relu'))
#        network.add(layers.Flatten())
        network.add(layers.Dropout(0.8))

        network.add(layers.Dense(64,activation='relu'))
        network.add(layers.Dropout(0.8))

        network.add(layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'))
        network.add(layers.Dropout(0.8))

        network.add(layers.Dense(64,activation='relu'))
        network.add(layers.Dropout(0.8))

        network.add(layers.Dense(32,activation='relu'))
        network.add(layers.Dropout(0.8))

        network.add(layers.Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))
        network.compile(optimizer='adam',
                    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])

    network.fit(X, y, epochs=5, batch_size=128)

    return network
```

The above is my keras neural network for an Open AI gym environment. I got my data and stored it like so

```html
[ [obs , reward , done , info ] , [ 0 , 1 ] ] 

[ 0 , 1 ] for 0 and [ 1 , 0 ] for 1.
```

The **y** variable is the **[  0 , 1 ]** and the  **x** variable is **[obs , reward , done , info ] **

What is the proper way to fit this data to my neural network??

Comment: Is this `[ [obs , reward , done , info ] , [ 0 , 1 ] ] ` your `y` variable ?, If so your `y` should only have the labels. Since your labels are already in one-hot encoded, you do not need to use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, normal `categorical_crossentropy` is to be used. Also, use `softmax` as the output activation function since either 1 or 0 would be the output.

Comment: The **y** variable is the **[  0 , 1 ]** and the  **x** variable is **[obs , reward , done , info ] **

Comment: Have you tried using categorical crossentropy as the loss function and softmax as the activation for the final layer ?

Comment: yes I have done that

Comment: Since you are trying to do reinforcement learning, try using keras-rl, which deals with RL problems. You can see the sample code for cartpole problem here https://hub.packtpub.com/build-reinforcement-learning-agent-in-keras-tutorial/